# How to remove namespace from HTML content in XML file

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm receiving an XML file via API and parsing it with PHP / SimpleXML / XPath.

I need to take data from one of the fields that contains HTML and output it, however the HTML is all prefixed with a "h:" namespace.

Example XML:

```
<xmlfeed>
 <title>Title Here</title>
  <a:content xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">   
    <h:table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="1360" height="259" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
     <h:tbody><h:tr><h:td width="35%" colspan="3"></h:td></h:tr></h:tbody>
    </h:table>
  <h:h3 xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Test heading here</h:h3>
  <h:a href="link.php">Link Here</h:a>
 </a:content>
</xmlfeed>
```

How can I parse all the HTML within a:content to remove the "h:" prefix from each element as well as the namespaces?

Thank you.

Comment: 1) Please show us what code you have already; it's much easier for us to add to your code than design it from scratch; 2) When you say "remove the namespaces" do you mean "remove the namespace prefix declarations"?

Comment: 1. I really don't have much, basically just $course_info = $xml->xpath('//a:content'); and wanting to echo $course_info to get the HTML. 2. And yes, I do mean remove the NS prefix declarations, thank you.
I didn't think I was trying anything new here, and it may be easy to just remove them and get regular HTML.

Comment: Note: I am a developer just working with the XML and was asked to output the HTML from that field. If this is something that should be handled via a namespace declaration on the front end (that all browsers will understand) so that the HTML will be treated as if it did not have the prefixes, then that information would be useful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have glossed over [this](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.removeattributens.php) in the documentation.

It took a little while to find, but  the following seems to work well:

```
$content = $xpath->query('a:content/h:*', $context);
foreach ($content as $piece)
{
    $piece->removeAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'h');
    $html_content .= $dom->saveXML($piece);
}
```

Hope this helps someone else trying to solve the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not well-versed in PHP or simpleXML, but since no one else has answered, I'll take a stab at it. (I do know XML and XPath well.)

The children of the `<a:content>` element in your input are XHTML elements. Most browsers will recognize XHTML. It's an XML vocabulary in the XHTML namespace that's otherwise very close to HTML.

So I don't think you need to remove any namespaces. Instead, select the children of `<a:content>`, using

```
$xml->xpath('//a:content/node()')
```

and output each one. (Sounds like you need to serialize each one, not just echo their value.)

Note that in order for the above XPath expression to work, you first need to register the `a` namespace prefix (see [registerXPathNamespace](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php) and the examples there).

Hopefully this gets you further down the road. Let me know if you have additional questions.